# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment stops inside VerticalViewPager

Tags: android, video, youtube-api

I am developing an app with YouTubeVideoPlayer and Images inside VerticalViewPager. When I swipe to video fragment player throws below error.

`YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. 
The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.`

For example let's say I have Video on 2nd page. If I swipe from 1st to 2nd it will work, but when I swipe from 3rd to 2nd it gives above error. I know YouTubePlayer doesn't support any view over it or padding. In my layout there is nothing which is on top of player.

In the FrameLayout @+id/frame,YouTubePlayerSupportFragment is added. In error log it shows root layout(RelativeLayout) overlaps the player.

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bg"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_5"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frame"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_200" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rel_control"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_5">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:id="@+id/img_mute"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_23"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_23"
                            android:src="@drawable/mute" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:id="@+id/img_fullscreen"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_22"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/fullscreen" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/dejavuserif"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="How to be happy? Ideas from the world's happiest Man!"
                            android:textColor="#292929"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_15"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/dejavusans_condensed"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:text="Buddhist monk, Matthieu Ricard has been called the World's happiest man. It was found that while meditating, Ricard's mind remained at an unusually clam state. Here he shares formula of his happiness."
                            android:textColor="#808080"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_web"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/dejavusans_extralight"
                            android:text="By:Sample Website"
                            android:textColor="#808080"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_10"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_more"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_50"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_50"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/more_arrow"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_1"
                    android:background="@color/blue_DEDEDF"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_5">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_like"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:src="@drawable/sel_heart" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_bookmark"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:src="@drawable/sel_bookmark" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_share"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/anim_share"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_11" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit** Fragment code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment).commit();
        mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (!isVisibleToUser && mYoutubePlayer != null) {
        mYoutubePlayer.pause();
        mYoutubePlayer.release();

    }
    if (isVisibleToUser && mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment).commit();
        mYouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to pause players as soon as they are not visible anymore.

Another solution could be to use this alternative player [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player). It's open source and based on YouTube's web player, therefore it has no issues with overlaying views.

Comment: Yes. I used setUserVisibleHint() method to initialize YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and pause player when it is visible and invisible respectively.
Also Thanks for the nice lib. I have gone through your lib before. But it would be good for me if I can solve this without lib.

Comment: double check that you are calling play only on the visible player.